# jquery cycle: after slideshow cycles once, restart on one and stop

Tags: jquery

So I have jQuery cycle running and I need help on how to set the parameters so the slideshow cycles through once and then starts back on the first position and just stops. I have text that scroll through with the images. Now I can get the image to cycle back putting a function on "end" but the text on one does not activate when I do this, here is my parameters settings:

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults = {
    fx:           'fade', // one of: fade, shuffle, zoom, scrollLeft, etc
    timeout:       4000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto 
    speed:         4000,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value)
    pagerEvent:   'hover', // event which drives the pager navigation
    end: function() {$('#slideshow').cycle('next'); },
    sync:          1,     // true if in/out transitions should occur simultaneously
    nowrap:        1      // true to prevent slideshow from wrapping

};
```

Does anyone know who to get the cycle to run through just once and then jump back to one then just stop with the link activated again? I tried using the autostop and autoStopCount but I do not want to indicate an exact number to make it stop. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

See http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/end.html and try this or something similar.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    autostop: 1, 
    end:      function(options) {  
        $('#slideshow').cycle(0).cycle('stop');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried using this code and got a strange result. The slideshow moves along to the last slide, stops, then the navigation continues animate active the first slide signifier even though the actual slides themselves stay paused on the last slide. Any ideas?

Comment: This answer solved the issue of getting cycle to go through slides once and stop on first slide again. Please accept.