# Make JQuery Cycle Plugin automatically play once through and stop at end of slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

How might I make the Cycle plugin automatically play once through and then stop at the end of the slideshow? Additionally, Id like to have a pause/play navigation button fade in that can be used to restart it once again by the user.

Is this possible?

## EDIT 1

Here is what I tried, but the slideshow still continued...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 3000, 
        speed: 500,
        autostop: 0,
        end: function(options) {  
               $('#gallery').cycle('stop');
                }
    });
});
```

## EDIT 2

I now currently have the slideshow successfully ending on the last slide, however I believe by using these particular parameters it may be causing problems with the play/pause toggle feature that is available to the plugin...

What happens is, the pause/play button does function, however once the slideshow is completely over it no longer does anything and will not allow the slideshow to start over.

Here is what I currently have scripted out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 3000, 
        speed: 500,
        autostop: 1 // Stop slideshow at end
    });

    $('a#pause_resume_button').click(function() { 
        $('#gallery').cycle('toggle'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an end option.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Pair this with stop and you're sorted.

If you know the number of slides then you could also use autoStop.

**EDIT:**

```
$('#scroller').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 3000, 
        speed: 500,
        autostop: 1,
        end: function(options) {  
          $('#gallery').cycle('stop');
          alert('finished');
        }
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/icohen/1/

**EDIT 2:**

http://jsbin.com/icohen/2/edit

Comment: A main caveat is the # of slides is always changing...is there no way to declare this without a specified slide count?

Comment: Put a function in the end property that calls stop.

Comment: with `autostop`, do i need to leave it set to its default, ie. "0"? ...Ive updated my original question with an example.

Comment: You don't need autoStop and end. Either will do it. Remove autoStop

Comment: Hmmm..I thought the Cycle plugin required `autostop` to use `end`, no?

Comment: Well i removed autostop and Im still not having any luck unfortunately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065198/jquery-cycle-after-slideshow-cycles-once-restart-on-one-and-stop

Comment: I've amended the answer for you.

Comment: So what does `autostop:1` do? I didnt see that as an option in the Cycle page but it does seem to work.

Comment: 1 must be YES, and 0 is NO i presume.

Comment: autostop:  true (1) to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count).

Comment: I do have 1 small issue now, ive highlighted the issue in my original question...

Comment: Funny example, lol. A couple things though... (1) Im trying to utilize the toggle command instead of pause and resume since it consolidates the two into one button...(2) additionally, your example seems to have the same problem which is, once the slideshow ends - if you click "resume" it still does not start over again :(

Comment: I opted to simply remove the pause play and only use PREV/NEXT click events instead. Easier solution since I couldnt figure it out. I checked off your answer though since you did technically answer the bulk of my original question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this property in your code

```
autostop: 0, // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count)
```

Call this to resume your slide show

```
$('#slideshow').cycle('resume');
```